# KeyError In Python With json.dumps

Tags: python, xml, json, urllib2

I'm trying to work with dictionaries inside a list in a JSON file. The data imports fine and reads fine. For the life of me I can't figure out how to printout the "member_id" keys. I just want to print the list of "member_id" numbers. I was initially using json.loads, then switched to json.dumps. Any help would really be appreciated.

```
import urllib2
import json
nyt_api_key = '72c9a68bbc504e91a3919efda17ae621%3A7%3A70586819'
url= 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/politics/v3/us/legislative/congress/113'
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(json_obj)
data2 = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=True, skipkeys = True)

print data2
```

Output from `print data2`: (The list goes on and on so it is truncated. There is a closing bracket at the bottom of the list. So it's dictionaries within a list.)

```
 "positions": [
 {
  "dw_nominate": "0.466", 
  "member_id": "A000055", 
  "vote_position": "Yes"
 }, 
 {
  "dw_nominate": "0.995", 
  "member_id": "A000367", 
  "vote_position": "Yes"
 }, 
 {
  "dw_nominate": "0.666", 
  "member_id": "A000369", 
  "vote_position": "Yes"
 },
```

Output from `print data2['member_id']`, output is the same if using 'positions', 'vote_position', etc.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/untitled2/1", line 9, in <module>
    print data2["positions"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Output from `print data`:

`u'positions': [{u'dw_nominate': u'0.466', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'A000055'}, {u'dw_nominate': u'0.995', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'A000367'}, {u'dw_nominate': u'0.666', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'A000369'}`

Output from `print data['positions']`:

`print data["positions"]
KeyError: 'positions'`

Output from `print.data(keys)`:

```
[u'status', u'results', u'copyright']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `json.dumps` returns `string` and hence the exception. try `print data['member_id']`

Comment: `json.dumps` produces a **string** so that's what you're assigning to `data2` (from object `data` which is apparently a list of dicts).  What are you trying to accomplish?!

Comment: @AkashShende it looks like `data` is a list of dicts so `data['member_id']` will also fail -- something like `data[0]['member_id']` might be fine, but with no idea of what the OP is trying to accomplish it's essentially just a guess:-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli, *I just want to print the list of "member_id" numbers.*

Comment: Output from `print data`:

`u'positions': [{u'dw_nominate': u'0.466', u'vote_position':   u'Yes', u'member_id': u'A000055'}, {u'dw_nominate': u'0.995', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'A000367'}, {u'dw_nominate': u'0.666', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'A000369'}`

Using `print data["member_id"]` or `print data ["u'member_id"]` I still get a KeyError. The for loop mentioned below by @PadraicCunningham returns `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`. I haven't exhausted that solution yet, still trying a couple of things with it. 
@AlexMartelli
@Akash Shende

Comment: @spacemonkey, what does `print data2["positions"]` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `print data2["positions"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @spacemonkey, meant `data["positions"]`, using .dumps you have a string.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It seems as though finding the string index of each number I'm looking for is a solution, albeit ad hoc. It would probably work but there a lot of things that could throw it off and I'll be running this on many pages of data. This is just the first. one.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `print data["positions"]
KeyError: 'positions'`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That was my initial plan but it wouldn't work. json.dumps at least formatted it into something readable. The keys under `data` are formatted `{"u'member_id" : "A000123"}`

Comment: one last thing `print data.keys()`

Comment: added `print data.keys()`

Comment: ok try the update in my answer, if that is no good you need to `print data["results"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I should change the heading of this to Scrapping JSON for XML in Python. I'm sure not everyone else would have the same issues I did with JSON but after many frustrating hours I decided to go down path #2... the xml version. The xml version was much easier to work with right out of the gate. In about 1/10 the time I got what I was looking for.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from xml.dom import minidom

feed = urlopen("http://api.nytimes.com/svc/politics/v3/us/legislative.xml?

doc = minidom.parse(feed)
id_element = doc.getElementsByTagName("member_id")
id_number0 = id_element[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue #just a sample
id_number1 = id_element[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue #just a sample
id_number2 = id_element[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue #just a sample

print len(id_element) #to see how many items were in the variable 


count = 0
for item in id_element:
    print id_element[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    count = count + 1
    if count == 434:
    break
```

This is definitely not the cleanest loop. I'm still working on that. But the code solves the problem that I had originally posted. The API key is not the actual one, formatting in the answer window was throwing it off so I just erased a bunch of it. You can find the API at the NYT developer website.

Thanks to everyone who posted.

Answer (score 1):

`data2` is a string value, it doesn't have keys. I think what you want to print is `data["positions"]`

That's a weird output from data, you don't even have the braces. Try printing the `type(data)`, it should be `dict`

Answer (score 1):

*I just want to print the list of "member_id" numbers.*

So you need to loop over `positions` and access the `member_id` in each dict:

```
data ={"positions": [
 {
  "dw_nominate": "0.466",
  "member_id": "A000055",
  "vote_position": "Yes"
 },
 {
  "dw_nominate": "0.995",
  "member_id": "A000367",
  "vote_position": "Yes"
 },
 {
  "dw_nominate": "0.666",
  "member_id": "A000369",
  "vote_position": "Yes"
 }]}

print([d["member_id"] for d in data["results"]["positions"]])
['A000055', 'A000367', 'A000369']
```

If you look at the [API documentation](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/congress_api/congress_api_examples#member-list-json) there are examples of each json response.

Comment: as soon as I get it to work I'll post the answer or the work around